# Finding the polygon that encompasses some points, but others must be outside

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I have a convex/concave hull problem that must include some vertices, but not all of them. Some points must be outside of the polygon and some are optional.

I took a look at Graham's scan algorithm, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. Since I have these optional vertices and these points that must be outside the resulting polygon.

**For example:**

- Points that must be included: (0,0),(10,4),(0,5),(2,4).
- Points that are optional: (2,3),(4,3).
- Points that must be outside: (3,2).

The resulting polygon would be with the points: (0,0),(2,3),(10,4),(0,5).

- If I were to just use the first 3 points, (3,2) would be inside. So we use the optional (2,3), but we don't need (4,3).

So this would be the result: (Red line marks an invalid path taken)

[image]

Is there an algorithm that can solve this problem already? I can only find algorithms that would include everything.

Thank you! :)

Comment: Must the vertices of the polygon lie on the points themselves? If so, it's easy to construct examples which are impossible, e.g.
$$\text{good:} \quad (0,0),\ (0,2),\ (2,0),\quad \text{bad:}\quad (0,1),\ (1,0)$$

Comment: Yes, they do. I can't use other points other then the ones given. In case of impossible situations, I must also know if that happens.

Comment: Which language do you use ? With Matlab and its functions 'convhull' and 'inpolygon', it's done in 5 lines. A general trend in scientific computing is to use "building blocks" and avoid redo all out of scratch.

Comment: I'm actually using C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an update. I haven't found anything that helped me, but this is how I solved the problem:

- I have organization groups that dictates the order of points I'm traveling. Let's call it PointGroup.
- The polygon in the original example would be a group with this points in this order: (0,0),(2,3),(10,4),(0,5). The last points connects with the first point as well.

The algorithm:

1. Create several PointGroups, each containing a different only one mandatory point. So far the perimeter is 0, and it's not a polygon.
2. Pick the PointGroup with smallest perimeter.
3. Check if:

   - It contains at least 3 points (is it a polygon?).
   - All mandatory points are in the group.
   - A point that needs to be outside is inside. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon)
4. If the condition fails:

   - Create several child PointGroups, each by adding a single point. I try every possibility using mandatory and possible points.
   - Return to 2.
5. If the condition succeeds, this PointGroup is the answer to the problem.

Not sure if this is optimal, but it works.